# Possessive pronouns

Tags: pronouns, word-order, possessives

Does a first-person possessive pronoun have to come last if it is in a list with others?"

> "My irresponsible sister loves jewelry, so she took both Sally's and mine.
>
> "The same room was marked on Joe's and my map."

I know it is much better to simply use a plural pronoun such as *our* or *their*, but I can not find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: I would say "mine and Sally's", and "mine and Joe's map".  However I can't give a formal explanation why so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: Note that "mine" is a *predicative adjective* that doesn't directly attach to the noun (i.e. "jewelry"), so the order of possessives doesn't matter so much - I think it comes down to the particular sentence and how it sounds or what emphasis you want to give. I probably would use either order equally often. Whereas "my" is an *attributive adjective* that would normally be immediately followed by the noun (i.e. "map"), so it would sound weird to say "my and Joe's map". But maybe someone can post a more learned answer on this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any hard and fast rules on whether you put yourself first or last.
I would however amend the second example, which at the moment doesn't clearly indicate whether it is a map shared by Joe and yourself, or you and Joe both have separate maps. Use either "...on Joe's' map and on mine" or "...on the map that Joe and I were using" to make this clear.